# Extract month and year from date in Batch file

Tags: batch-file

I need to get the month and year of current system date stored in two different variables using a batch file. The month format should be MMM and year should be yyyy. For eg. Today's date is 10th June 2019. So month variable should have June and year variable should have 2019.
Can anyone please help me with this?

Thanks.

Comment: Any example of the file? Are the variables named in a way that would help? Any code you tried? Anyway, I'd cut the promising parts using regex, then try to parse them.

Comment: just to clarify:  `MMM` is "short month name" (three letters). `MM` is "two digits" and `MMMM` is "full month name". So you actually are looking for `MMMM`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`cmd` has [no easy way](https://www.computerhope.com/forum/index.php?topic=147126.0) to get the month name, but if you are willing to (ab)use Powershell:

```
for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=_" %%a in ('powershell get-date -UFormat "%%Y_%%B"') do set "y=%%a" & set "m=%%b"
echo Year is %y% and month is %m%
```

Consult the [documetation](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility/Get-Date?view=powershell-3.0) about what formats are available.

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to hard code a list of your Month abbreviations (or names), then it isn't too difficult to do with pure batch.

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion

set "months= 1:Jan 2:Feb 3:Mar 4:Apr 5:May 6:Jun 7:Jul 8:Aug 9:Sep 10:Oct 11:Nov 12:Dec"

for /f "skip=1 tokens=1,2" %%X in (
  '"wmic path win32_localtime get month, year"'
) do if "%%Y" neq "" for /f %%M in ("!months:* %%X:=!") do (
  set "month=%%M"
  set "year=%%Y"
)

echo month=!month! year=!year!
```

The leading space in the value of `months` is important.

The `IF` statement is needed because WMIC produces UTF-16 output, and there is a flaw in the conversion to ANSI when parsed by `FOR /F` that leads to an extra line consisting of nothing but a carriage return (0x0D). The `IF` statement filters out the unwanted "empty" line.